# Apache Camel Seda Route still modifies my main routes body

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the Camel route which I am working on. The route takes a CSV file from one directory in the sftp to another directory inside the sftp while carrying out a transformation to XML.

```
from(mySftp.getUri("/camel"))
   .choice()
       .when(body().isNull())
           .log("No Files Found")
       .otherwise()
           .process(new Processor() {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String body =  exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).toString();
                String [] lines = body.split("\n");
                for(String line : lines) {
                      String [] fields = line.split(",");
                      //trasformation here
                }
                exchange.setProperty("generatedXml", sb.toString());
                }
}).to(mySftp.getUri("/camel/archive"))
```

This works perfectly fine until I call a `seda route` i have defined which its purpose is to send an SNS by setting the body and required headers.

The code is below.

```
from("seda:sendSNS")
.setBody().simple("message")
.setHeader("CamelAwsSnsSubject", simple("subject"))
.to(myInfoSns.getUri());
```

and this is how I am calling my `seda route` by using "to"

```
 from(mySftp.getUri("/camel"))
   .to("seda:sendSNS")
   .choice()
       .when(body().isNull())
           .log("No Files Found")
       .otherwise()
           .process(new Processor() {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String body =  exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).toString();
                String [] lines = body.split("\n");
                for(String line : lines) {
                      String [] fields = line.split(",");
                      //trasformation here
                }
                exchange.setProperty("generatedXml", sb.toString());
                }
}).to(mySftp.getUri("/camel/archive"))
```

I am expecting that although I am calling the seda route and setting its body within, this should not affect my body of my main route. It seems like my XML gets generated successfully but then my main route is failing to move the file to the required destination.

The error which I am getting is

```
Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: camel/archive/file.csv

No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: RemoteFile[file.csv] of type: org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFile on: file.csv. Caused by: Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value [Body is file based: \tmp\file.csv] due \tmp\file.csv (The system cannot find the file specified). Exchange[ID-IT1289-1521106847220-0-1]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException - Error during type conversion from type: java.lang.String to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value [Body is file based: \tmp\file.csv] due \tmp\file.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)]
```

Any ideas what may be the cause of this? Why is my file no longer found after I call my `seda route "sendSNS"`.

Comment: Did you want seda or wiretap?

Comment: I have tried wiretap, although when I come to use wiretap inside a choice() I am stopped `The method when(Predicate) is undefined for the type WireTapDefinition<ChoiceDefinition>`

Comment: Are you routing to `"seda:sendSNS"` conditionally? If yes, what's the condition? Otherwise, why do you use it in `when`?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Before I send the file to the archive, I wish to send another sns that the XML generated Successfully.... `.wireTap("seda:sendSNS")
   .choice()
       .when(body().isNull())
           .log("No Files Found")
       .otherwise()
           .process(new Processor() {
               sb = new StringBuilder();
                //transofmration
                exchange.setProperty("generatedXml", sb.toString());
                }
   })
  .wireTap("seda:sendSNS")
  .to(mySftp.getUri("/camel/archive"))
 .endChoice()`

Answer (score 3):

Your intention is to send a copy of the message to the `seda` endpoint, so the integration you need is `wireTap`:

```
from(mySftp.getUri("/camel"))
  .wireTap("seda:sendSNS")
  .choice()
  //the rest...
```

Related documentation is [here](http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html):

> Wire Tap (from the EIP patterns) allows you to route messages to a separate location while they are being forwarded to the ultimate destination.

Comment: i tried this, although when I come to use wiretap inside a choice() I am stopped `The method when(Predicate) is undefined for the type WireTapDefinition<ChoiceDefinition>`

Comment: Use endChoice to go back to choice (eg read as end this block and go back to choice)